# Is there support for resumed TLS connections with NSUrlCredential/NSUrlConnection

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, nsurlcredential

TLS handshaking on every micro request is not a good idea. I read about resumed TLS sessions that have less overhead. I'm not clear if this is supported in NSUrlConnection when used with NSUrlCredential/NSUrlCredentialStorage.
Has anyone had some experience with this and knows if the TLS session information is also stored or re-negotiated?

Cheers K